# MVC Kendo Grid multiselect column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo mvc grid.

I want one of the columns to be a list a values.

For example my data object:

```
public TestObject()
{
  public int TestID {get; set;}
  public string MyTest {get; set;}
  public string MyCategory {get; set;}
  public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

Kendo Grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyProject.BusinessObjects.TestObject>()
        .Name("myGrid")
        .Columns(col => 
        {
            col.Bound(x => x.TestID);
            col.Bound(x => x.MyTest);
            col.Bound(x => x.MyCategory);
            col.Bound(x => x.Description);
            col.Command(x => { x.Edit(); x.Destroy(); });
        })
        .Selectable()
        .Scrollable()
        .ToolBar(x => x.Create())
        .Sortable()
        .Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
        .Pageable(p => p
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
        .DataSource(d => d
            .Ajax()
            .Read(r => r.Action("GetData", "MyController"))
            .PageSize(20)
            .Model(m => 
            {
                m.Id(x => x.TestID);                    
            })      
            .Update("UpdateData", "MyController")
            .Create("CreateData", "MyController")
            .Destroy("DeleteData", "MyController")
        )
   )
```

Now when the user goes to add or edit a record I want the MyCategory to show a list of valid values. (Basically MyCategory is a FK but is not enforced that way in the DB)

How can I accomplish this with the Kendo Grid?  I was trying to follow the Kendo online example but I'm missing the connection when they create a ViewState object and how the grid interacts with that particular object. 
 (Kendo Grid Editing custom editor example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesnt have to be fk in DB.

```
columns.ForeignKey(p => p.MyCategory, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["MyCategory"], "Id", "MyCategoryText");
```

and in controller index page you have to populate the viewdata. You can get the data from DB or you hardcode the values too.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {            
        ViewData["MyCategory"] =  GetMyCategoryList();
        return View();
    }

 public List<SelectListItem> GetMyCategoryList()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> lstMyCategory = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var data = new[]{
             new SelectListItem{ Id=1,MyCategoryText="Federal"},
             new SelectListItem{ Id=2,MyCategoryText="General"},
             new SelectListItem{ Id=3,MyCategoryText="Cash"},                 
         };
        lstMyCategory = data.ToList();
        return lstMyCategory;
    }
```

Comment: That almost achieves what I want to do. It enforces the data so the user cant save a rouge category.  However from the add/edit I would like the category field to be a dropdown of those values like in the Kendo example.